# $cookieStore expiration time not working in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have used $cookieStore  in angularjs with expiration time but expiration time is not working.

Look at this code...

```
var today = new Date();
var expiresValue = new Date(today);
//Set 'expires' option in (365 x 24 x 60 x 60) = 31536000 seconds = 1 year
expiresValue.setSeconds(today.getSeconds() + 31536000); 
// Setting a cookie
$cookieStore.put('STYPE', response.data.type, {'expires' : expiresValue});
```

How can i set expiration time in angularjs.

Comment: Can you please  select the answer if it helped you

Answer (score 2):

`$cookieStore` is depricated. Instead of using `$cookieStore` use `$cookies`

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies

```
$cookies.put('STYPE', response.data.type, {expires : expiresValue});
```

Comment: Hi, 
I am using angular version 1.2.32 in my *ancient* project. There I am able to use put function with $cookieStore but not with $cookies. Could you please help me in understanding how I can set the expiry there? Currently the expiry is not being set even when I am using the below line:

$cookieStore.put("newotpcookieobject", '7668787', { 'expires': expiresValue });